# Do I need EUFI on an all linux system?

Tags: uefi, grub2

I only use various Linux OS,  Ubuntu mainly.
One of my PCs has stopped booting from the Hard drive and while I can boot it from a rescatux CD it will not repair it. 
I would cheerfully live without UEFI. Is this possible? Can I just re-install grub2 without UEFI partition? 
Thanks in advance
R.

Comment: Could the non-booting hard drive just be damaged or need GRUB or something re-installed? Why / what says you need UEFI?

Comment: Do I need UEFI is really what I am asking. I am ill informed on this as most of my boxes are old and I have never come across UEFI before.

Answer (score 0):

No, Linux can boot fine in legacy mode (at least the distros Ive worked with - includining Ubuntu) will work fine with a bootloader on the MBR.

To remove UEFI booting you need to modify the BIOS to legacy mode. I dont thonk you need to remove the UEFI partition, but you will want grub installed on the mbr ideally.